# Teamcity - Reporting Code Coverage via Service Message

Tags: teamcity-8.0

We have a custom test runner for our UI Smoke Tests and I want to report code coverage to TeamCity to enable metrics monitoring and failing of build, etc.

I'm trying the use service messages to achieve this as follows:

```
##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='CodeCoverageAbsMCovered' value='5']
##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='CodeCoverageAbsMTotal' value='10']
```

But it's not being picked up.  Can someone please tell me how to send coverage data to Teamcity.

Thanks,
dave

Answer (score 0):

The key used in service messages should not be equal to any of [predefined keys](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Custom+Chart#CustomChart-predefinedStatisticsKeys).